# Change frame color of grase pencil

Tags: keyframes, color, grease-pencil

The Grease Pencil's keyframe color and thickness is quite similar to keyframes of object from viewport. Is there way I could edit the thickness and color of the grease pencil keyframes so it doesn't look so confusing?

Comment: All keyframes are equal. In the dopesheet you can manually set the [keyframe type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/animation/keyframes/introduction.html#keyframe-types) for each keyframe, so it displays in a different colour.